# Majority filter python

Tags: python, filtering

I am trying to create a function, which will replace a list element with the value that occurs maximum number of times adjacent to it within a given frame of say x elements.

Eg-

- A=[2,2,2,3,2,1,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8]
- If x=5, the modified list should be- 
  A=[2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,8,8,8,8]

---

I have done the naive sliding window implementation. 
Is there any built in function or *pythonic* way to do this?

Comment: How do you get 5 x 2s and 5 x 5s?

Comment: @JonClements: I assume the 6 gets converted to a 5, but what happened to the 1 is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: I assume the 3 and 1 are converted to 2, but the max is 5 so the 6 x 2s becomes 5 x 2s

Comment: I don't understand what you are seeking. You drop (1, 3, 6) and add (2, 5) using x = 5

Please give your implementation so we can understand you better.

Comment: i'm trying to remove the elements which occur infrequently among other more occuring elements. 3 is mostly surrounded by 2's. so replaced by a 2. same with 6. mostly surrounded by 5's so replaced by a 5.

Comment: x is the number of elements to be included in the frame while checking. In case of 1- Elements in frame will be- 3,2,1,4,4 (before 3 is replaced by a 2) So the max occurring element is 4 so 1 is replaced by 4

Comment: I think you have a typo in your output list since it's not the same length as the input list. As I mentioned earlier, the 1 seems to have disappeared. What's wrong with your naive sliding window implementation? I don't think there's a function in the standard modules to do this, but it's easy enough to do it in a couple of lines with a generator expression in a list comprehension.

Comment: @PM2Ring ya there was a typo. resolved it.  thanks. could you please give the generator expression? i'm a novice in python and was looking for something along those lines.

Comment: @amnk Let me know if you need more explanation about how my code works.

Comment: BTW, you really should have pasted your code into the question. You probably got most of those downvotes due to lack of code, and because people couldn't understand exactly what you wanted. If you'd shown some code it would have been a lot easier to figure out what you're trying to do (despite the typo that was originally in your expected output list). Also, seeing code gives people a rough idea of your coding skills, which can help people in formulating an answer that you'll understand. And when you post your own code it shows that you've made a sincere attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three implementation of a naive sliding window 1D majority filter.

The first one uses a "traditional" `for` loop, the second is virtually the same algorithm, but using a generator expression in a list comprehension. These both determine the majority element in a given window using

```
max(set(a), key=a.count)
```

where `a` is the window. We first create a set to get the unique elements in `a` and then find which of those elements has the highest count in `a`.

The third version uses the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is enhanced dictionary, to find the majority element.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import Counter

def majority_filter_traditional(seq, width):
    offset = width // 2
    seq = [0] * offset + seq
    result = []
    for i in range(len(seq) - offset):
        a = seq[i:i+width]
        result.append(max(set(a), key=a.count))
    return result

def majority_filter_listcomp(seq, width):
    offset = width // 2
    seq = [0] * offset + seq
    return [max(set(a), key=a.count) 
        for a in (seq[i:i+width] for i in range(len(seq) - offset))]

def majority_filter_counter(seq, width):
    offset = width // 2
    seq = [0] * offset + seq
    return [Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][0]
        for a in (seq[i:i+width] for i in range(len(seq) - offset))]

majority_filter = majority_filter_listcomp

seq = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]
print(seq)
print(majority_filter(seq, 5))
```

**output**

```
[2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

The above code will also work on Python 2. The Counter class is not in the standard library on versions earlier than Python 2.7, however there is [code available for Counter](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) which will work on Python 2.5.

Comment: thanks a lot! learnt so many new things today. i didn't even know about the max(iter, key) function. Read up on high performance containers also.  python is truly an amazing language.

Comment: This is not the same implementation as mentioned in http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/majority-filter.htm. It is not taking all neighbors into account (one in the row above and below).

Comment: @Abhijay The OP wanted a 1D filter. If you need help with a 2D filter please ask a new question.